# MakePen Object Mapper chip bug or not?

Tags: rec-room

Okay. So, I just noticed that when I created a grabbable object who's ID is being tracked by the `Object Mapper` chip. The chip does not register that I have grabbed it if I am holding the makerpen. Only once I let go of the makepen, grab the object, then recall the makerpen again will the `Object Mapper` chip register me holding it. If I try grabbing it while holding the makerpen, the chip does not register that I have grabbed it.

This makes it difficult to debug circuitry. Was this intentional? I think it might be there since the new release of the view gadgets update.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior has been there for a long time, and I believe it to be intentional. (Although we can never be sure, since there is no official documentation whatsoever.) When you are holding the maker pen, your off-hand behaves similar to the move tool, meaning that the object will snap, align and create an undo-actions.

So you will have to drop the maker pen to test the object mapper chip. That should not be too much of a problem though if you add some output chips and set the option in the palette settings to always see gadgets.